Is the sentence 'He used to play any sport' grammatically correct?
I do know that 'any' is used for questions and negations, nevertheless sentences like 'Parma loaned Laursen out before he would play any games for the club.' make me wonder if this sentence would work to say that he would practice every sport available at the time in his school or whatever place he was.
Probably the most used sentences would be 'He used to play every sport or he used to play every single sport or sports' but I would like to know if my proposed sentence is right.

Your example sentence seems to me to be an extension of the 'negation' use (Laursen had not yet played any games).  The sentence in the title needs an extension, for example He used to play any sport that was available (at his school, or at his local sports centre).

"He used to play any sport" is possible but isn't very idiomatic - I would say "He used to do any job", which implies he was desperate for work, but "He used to play every sport" sounds more natural (at least if he was enthusiastic about it - "any" implies you're desperate or desultory).

@PaulTanenbaum I want to express the idea that the person practically would practice every single sport available for him at the time.

The problem with your sentence is that the predominant context in which "play any sport" is used is one where a person's raw athleticism and coordination are the focus.

He was a born athlete who could play any sport.

That typical usage  doesn't jibe well with "used to".  Here's a sentence to show what I mean:

He used to be a born athlete.

With respect to any, the meaning of any there is whatever sport was being played, not "a single" or "even one"  as in your Parma example.
